# Some files lost during upgrade

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, macos-mojave, recovery

I was trying to upgrade my mid 2012 MacbookPro from High Sierra to Mojave.

While it was installing, status bar was stuck for a long time. After that, I forced restart with pressing I/O button. Device restarted but all of my Desktop's files and others was gone and I got laggy desktop. When I opened up disk utility, disk space size was equal as previous one.

So, after that, I partitioned some space for an installation on a new partition. I thought that I could recover my files with the new installation but it didn't work. I got usual clean macos, other partition size's are the same as before but I can't reach my files. When I click to my HDD, it ask me for a password, I complete password control but there are no files show, just only empty folders.

How can I get back my files?

Comment: First, stop using that computer immediately. If you are reading this on that computer, find another computer to continue reading. Every moment you are using the computer it is potentially writing over the files you want to recover.

Comment: nope, Im using different computer now. Also, I was using different partition on macbook.

Comment: Adding a partition does not prevent the old files from being overwritten, because it is all still happening on the same disk. Anyway, you will need another disk with empty space of about the same size as the used space on the problem disk for the recovered files to be stored on. You will need a file recovery program such as [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). Then you need some way of accessing the problem disk from the second computer. I do not know if using target disk mode will suffice - are you confident in removing the problem disk and attaching it to another computer?

Comment: Isn't PhotoRec for only files which is "image" ? I have many other types of files to rescue. Yes, I can remove my disk. Also, I have macbook air and windows pc as an alternative.

Comment: It can recover many other file types: [File Formats Recovered By PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec). At a guess the name comes from its original purpose but it has been extended to include more types. N.B. You don't get the original file names back.

Comment: That's great. I will try that program at this evening and I will share my result. I hope I can get back my files. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Ummm... don't let the other computer format the drive, and the best thing to do would be to make a complete *image* of the problem disk before working on that complete copy, so that if something goes horribly wrong then you still have the original problem disk, but I have no experience of doing that. [What Are Forensic Images and Forensic Copies?](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/what-are-forensic-images-and-forensic-copies)